# Download a file to a temp location in Swift 4 (Mac OS) like with curl

Tags: macos, swift4

I'm writing a CLI tool in Swift 4 for MacOS.
If I "cheat" and use a shell function, then the curl command, I get exactly the result I'm after:

```
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}

shell("/usr/bin/curl", "-OL", "http://mywebserver/myfile.whatever")
```

How do I do the same thing natively in Swift 4?
I tried using the just library: https://github.com/dduan/Just
but I can't figure out how to simply get it to download a file from a URL to a specific location on the file system.
I've also found various solutions for Swift 3 and 5, and iOS which obviously don't work for me.

Comment: The usual API is `dataTask` or `downloadTask` of `URLSession`. Because of its asynchronous behavior you have to start and stop the runloop.

Comment: Thanks.  There's seems to be plenty of useful documentation referring to these things on the Apple site:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession
However, as a beginner it's very difficult to translate this into working code.
Swift is a big learning curve for me, as whilst I've done this sort of thing in Bash and PHP for years, it's frankly a lot harder and more complicated in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example: Due to the asynchronous behavior of `URLSession` you have to start the runloop after resuming the data task and stop it in the completion handler.

```
let runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()
let url = URL(string: "http://mywebserver/myfile.whatever")!

let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    let returnValue : Int32
    if let error = error {
        fputs("\(error.localizedDescription)\n", stderr)
        returnValue = EXIT_FAILURE
    } else {
        let result = String(data:data!, encoding:.utf8)!
        fputs("\(result)\n", stdout)
        returnValue = EXIT_SUCCESS
    }
    CFRunLoopStop(runLoop)
    exit(returnValue)
}

dataTask.resume()
CFRunLoopRun()
```

The code returns the data in stdout. You can write the data directly to disk, replace

```
let result = String(data:data!, encoding:.utf8)!
fputs("\(result)\n", stdout)
```

with

```
 let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/me/path/to/file.ext")
 do {
    try data!.write(to: fileURL)
 } catch { 
   fputs("\(error.localizedDescription)\n", stderr)
 }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much!  That works great.  One slight problem though, although it works, I'm getting lots of strange errors in the STDOUT:
2020-03-25 21:45:25.611367-0300 download[13621:351164] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2974 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert
Program ended with exit code: 0

Any ideas what that could be about?

Comment: Those are obscure status messages, no errors. Ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

You can download using `downloadTask`

1. Create session configuration
2. Create URLSession with this configuration
3. Apply download task
4. When the download is done successfully, copy the data to the destination

```
let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!
let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("downloadedFile.jpg")

    //Create URL to the source file you want to download
let fileURL = URL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Martin#/media/File:Saint_martin_map.PNG")

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

    let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
            // Success
            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
            }

            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
            } catch (let writeError) {
                print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
            }

        } else {
            print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    task.resume()

  }
```

Comment: Thanks!  The script runs, but where is the file downloading to?
Is there a standard swift temp directory?
I never understood this "documentDirectory"..  The solution above works and allows a path to be specified for downloading of the file.

Comment: It is downloaded to document directory. 

Check the link.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-find-the-users-documents-directory

Comment: That only explains about iOS?  What about macOS?